# joomla mutiple backgrounds at the same time

Tags: html, css, joomla

I want to have multiple backgrounds at the same time, they will overlap each other.
I know it has to work but somehow it doesn't work for me.

code I have:

```
body{
height:100%;
width:100%;
background: 
url("../images/background/top-img-bg.jpg") no-repeat center top,
url("../images/background/bottom-img-bg.jpg") no-repeat center bottom,
url("../images/background/overlay-pattern.png") repeat-x left top;
}
```

I want to have an image stick to the top, an image stick to the bottom and a image that overlay the whole background.

http://jsfiddle.net/8LtEk/

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking your css into separate statements like below.  Using comma's to separate the individual background images and maintaining the same ordering for any other background properties:

```
background-image: url("../images/background/top-img-bg.jpg"), url("../images/background/bottom-img-bg.jpg"), url("../images/background/overlay-pattern.png");
background-position: center top, center bottom, left top;
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-x;
```

Also, this is one of those CSS3 features where browser support could be the culprit.